# Handling errors in express async middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, es6-promise

I have an `async` middleware in express, because I want to use `await` inside it, to clean up my code.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(async(req, res, next) => {
    await authenticate(req);
    next();
});

app.get('/route', async(req, res) => {
    const result = await request('http://example.com');
    res.end(result);
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {

    console.error(err);

    res
        .status(500)
        .end('error');
})

app.listen(8080);
```

The problem is that when it rejects, it doesn't go to my error middleware, but if I remove the `async` keyword and `throw` inside a middleware it does.

```
app.get('/route', (req, res, next) => {
    throw new Error('Error');
    res.end(result);
});
```

So I'm getting `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` instead of entering my error handling middleware, how can I let the error bubble up, and express handle it?

Comment: Here's a good article I found when i was googling about it: https://strongloop.com/strongblog/async-error-handling-expressjs-es7-promises-generators/

Answer (score 135, accepted):

> The problem is that when it rejects, it doesn't go to my error
>   middleware, but if I remove the async keyword and throw inside a
>   middleware it does.

`express` doesn't support promises currently, support may come in the future release of `express@5.x.x`

So when you pass a middleware function, `express` will call it inside a `try/catch` block.

```
Layer.prototype.handle_request = function handle(req, res, next) {
  var fn = this.handle;

  if (fn.length > 3) {
    // not a standard request handler
    return next();
  }

  try {
    fn(req, res, next);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

The problem is that `try/catch` won't catch a `Promise` rejection outside of an `async` function and since `express` does not add a `.catch` handler to the `Promise` returned by your middleware, you get an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

---

The easy way, is to add `try/catch` inside your middleware, and call `next(err)`.

```
app.get('/route', async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const result = await request('http://example.com');
        res.end(result);
    } catch(err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

But if you have a lot of `async` middlewares, it may be a little repetitive.

Since I like my middlewares as clean as possible, and I usually let the errors bubble up, I use a wrapper around `async` middlewares, that will call `next(err)` if the promise is rejected, reaching the express error handler and avoiding `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`

```
const asyncHandler = fn => (req, res, next) => {
    return Promise
        .resolve(fn(req, res, next))
        .catch(next);
};

module.exports = asyncHandler;
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
app.use(asyncHandler(async(req, res, next) => {
    await authenticate(req);
    next();
}));

app.get('/async', asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {
    const result = await request('http://example.com');
    res.end(result);
}));

// Any rejection will go to the error handler
```

---

There are also some packages  that can be used

- [async-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-middleware)
- [express-async-handler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler)

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the the framework [Koa](https://koajs.com/) (supposedly built by people who first worked on Express) has more built-in conveniences for async operations in request handlers and the kind of Promise awareness and error handling the OP was asking about.

Comment: Typescripted: `export const asyncHandler = (fn: RequestHandler) => (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next)`. Thanks!

Comment: More info on the `express@5.x.x` support: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html. I've tried `5.0.0-alpha.8`, and it works exactly as described: `route handlers and middleware that return a Promise will call next(value) automatically when they reject or throw an error.`.

Comment: Why can't asyncHandler be an async function itself too?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, Can you explain why you used `Promise.resolve(fn(...)).catch()` instead of simply `fn(...).catch()` ?

Comment: @cak3_lover otherwise this wrapper function is not asynchronous.  And the async again is needed because we also use an async function as `fn`, which in it's turn is calling `await request(...)`. Anyhow, I really really need Express 5.x!

Answer (score 45):

Well, I found this - https://github.com/davidbanham/express-async-errors/, then require the script and you are good to go

```
const express = require('express');
require('express-async-errors');
```

Comment: This module is still useful. As mentioned below, Express v5 will add support for async middlewares, but as of today there is no release of v5.

Comment: Too bad it doesn't work with routers

Comment: You saved my day. Thks :)

Comment: If you use a Router, you just have to require it at the beginning of each router file

Comment: Latest version of this library is from 2018 :\? With quite some issues in GitHub.

Answer (score 19):

Answer with asyncHandler is good and usefull, but it is still not comfortable to write this wrapper in every route. I propose to improve it:

```
const asyncHandler = fn => (req, res, next) => {
    return Promise
        .resolve(fn(req, res, next))
        .catch(next)
}

const methods = [
    'get',
    'post',
    'delete'  // & etc.
]

function toAsyncRouter(router) {
    for (let key in router) {
        if (methods.includes(key)) {
            let method = router[key]
            router[key] = (path, ...callbacks) => method.call(router, path, ...callbacks.map(cb => asyncHandler(cb)))
        }
    }
    return router
}
```

and now we can do that way:

```
const router = toAsyncRouter(express().Router())
router.get('/', someAsyncController)
```

and so one.

Minute ago added a npm module [async-express-decorator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-express-decorator).

Answer (score 8):

Express 5 now handle async promises:

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

> Starting with Express 5, route handlers and middleware that return a
> Promise will call next(value) automatically when they reject or throw
> an error. For example

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: when will express 5 be released?

Comment: `5.0.0-beta.1` is out now. I was using `4.18.2` and everything works the same, and now async error handling works.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use try-catch and in catch section just pass the error in next() parameter Like this -

```
async create(req, res, next) {

    try {
      const userProp = req.body;
      const user = new User(userProp)

      const response = await user.save()
      const token = await user.createJWSToken()

      res.send({response, token})

    } catch (err){
      next(err)
    }
}
```

And obviously put this express middleware on your index.js file.

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(422).send({ error: err.message });
});
```

Comment: But this sets a common 422 error code for all responses. What's wrong if I don't set up an error middleware and deal with all the errors inside the handler code, returning the wanted JSON and status?

Answer (score 4):

You need to callbackify your async handler. If you know the concept of promisify, this is the opposite. Callbackify is built-in in Node.

```
import util from 'util'

app.use(util.callbackify(async (req, res) => {
  await authenticate(req);
}));
```

What this does is that it returns a function with a third argument which would be the next function and calls it after the promise has been resolved. If the promise is rejected, the next function will be called with the error as an argument.