# How can I handle all errors in async express body

Tags: node.js, express

I want to write a global handler overall express **ASYNC** body function.

I am using

```
app.get('/api/0/get/whisper', (req, res) => { 
    res.send(a.b.c)
})
```

In this case, I am getting an error `ReferenceError: a is not defined` and error handler working perfectly.

```
// error handler
app.use((err, req, res, next) => { 
   res.status(500).send(`Internal Server Error`)
})
```

How can I use this handler for ASYNC body like this:

```
app.get('/api/0/get/whisper', async (req, res) => { 
    res.send(a.b.c)
})
```

My error handler not working for async function. Why?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Duplicate of [Handling errors in express async middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391080/handling-errors-in-express-async-middleware)

Comment: Check that other question, express does not handle promise rejections, you need to wrap the middleware or `try/catch` inside it.