# Why is my error handler in ExpressJS not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

I am building an api, with ExpressJS, for a project of mine and would like to implement error handling. I've read some articles on the internet on how to do this and tried a few ways of implementing error handling in my api. The problem that I have now is that my error handler doesn't work and I have no idea why. To make my problem more clear, here's what I already tried:

This is the bottom part of my index.js file:

```
// Controllers
app.use("/auth", require("./controllers/auth"));
app.use("/clients", require("./controllers/clients"));

// Error handling
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    logger.error(
        `date - ${new Date()}, message - ${err.message}, stack trace - ${
            err.stack
        }`
    );

    return res
        .status(500)
        .json({ status: 500, message: "Something went wrong." });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

As a side note: I am using WinstonJS for logging errors to files and Mongoose as the ORM for my MongoDB database.

This is the controller for the clients route (controllers/clients.js):

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const ClientsService = require("../services/clients");

// GET -> Get all clients -> /clients
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    const clients = await ClientsService.getAll();

    return res.status(200).json({ status: 200, data: clients });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And finally, this is the clients service (services/clients.js), the place where I would like to throw errors (maybe this isn't the right place to throw errors, please correct me if I am wrong):

```
const ClientModel = require("../models/Client");

const getAll = async () => {
    return ClientModel.findById({})
        .then(clients => clients)
        .catch(err => {
            throw new Error(err);
        });
};

module.exports = { getAll };
```

As you can see, I put an empty object in the function for findById. This is to force an error, so that I can test the error handling. A few lines below that, I throw an error. I expect this to fire the middleware function that I defined in index.js. That middleware function, as shown in the code for index.js, logs the error to a file and then sends a 500 response to the client (read 'user').

Instead of this, I actually get an error in the console called 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning'. Here's the error:

```
(node:15416) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{}" at path "_id" for model "clients"
    at D:\projects\myproject\services\clients.js:7:10
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async D:\projects\myproject\controllers\clients.js:8:18
(node:15416) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15416) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise 
rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Why is my error handling not working? If you have a solution, how would I be able to enable error handling for my code?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the [express error handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) documentation, it says:

> You must catch errors that occur in asynchronous code invoked by route
>   handlers or middleware and pass them to Express for processing.

So you need to catch the error, and pass it to the express error middleware using `next(err)`:

So your controller needs to be updated like this:

```js
router.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const clients = await ClientsService.getAll();
    return res.status(200).json({ status: 200, data: clients });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

Also you had better to return a promise from your service like this which is clearer:

```js
const getAll = () => {
  return ClientModel.findById({});
};
```

Now if you are concerned to use try catch in every route, you may check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51391081/11717458) answer to avoid it.

Comment: I tried to mock it by throwing an error outside of the try/catch block or throwing an error inside the catch block. They could not be handled by the error handler. Is there a way to handle the "unexpected" errors?

Answer (score 2):

Make the try/catch before calling the async function

```
try{
    const clients = await ClientsService.getAll();
    return res.status(200).json({ status: 200, data: clients });
}catch(err){
    return res.status(500).json({ status: 500, message: 'There was a problem :' + err });
}
```

Comment: Does that mean that I will have to wrap every controller in a try/catch statement?

Comment: You could throw the error inside the promise or reject the promise instead.

Comment: In the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/catch) you can find useful examples

Answer (score -1):

If it helps anyone, you should be able to get this down to fairly tidy syntax like this:

```
this._expressApp.get('/api/somedata', this._catch(this._router.myDataRoute));
```

Some example code of mine [here](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/host/startup/httpServerConfiguration.ts) - see also the [blog post from Alex Bazhenov](https://medium.com/@Abazhenov/using-async-await-in-express-with-node-8-b8af872c0016).