# Control a headless chrome instance from a web site

Tags: puppeteer, headless-browser, captiveportal

We are running a captive portal WIFI solution.
When people connect to it websites such as Google and Facebook are blocked.
We want to allow users to go to our partners websites but they have network requests to Google and Facebook.

The only way around this that I can think of is running a headless chrome instance on our server and allow our users to connect to that. Our users would need to control the headless instance from their browser.
Is this possible?
Does any one have any other suggestions of how I can get around this problem?

Comment: This is pretty broad, but see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66946923/6243352) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939503/puppeteer-doesnt-close-browser/67910262#67910262) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225461/puppeteer-unable-to-run-on-heroku/67596057#67596057) for some examples of Express and Puppeteer. I'm not sure if it's the best solution to this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working om something like that https://github.com/KaanDoesNothing/Browser-Proxy