# Problem with async error handling with Express

Tags: javascript, express, async-await

I am trying to avoid the try catch block in route handlers. I am trying to catch the error in the following manner:

```
const catchAsync = (fn) => {

    // why this function does not have access to req,res,next?
    // I am passing async(req,res,next) as an argument, hence
    // req,res,next should be known to this function

    fn(req, res, next).catch((err) => next(err));
  
};
```

and then in the route handler:

```
exports.createTour = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const newTour = await Tour.create(req.body);
  res.status(201).json({
    status: "success",
    data: {
      tour: newTour,
    },
  });
});
```

Now the problem is that, I don't understand why the function `fn(req,res,next)` inside the `catchAsync` function block, does not have access to `(req,res,next)` when called ?
All I understand is that I am passing `async(req,res,next)` as an argument to `catchAsync` function. Hence when the function gets called inside the `catchAsync` block, it should have access to `req,res,next`

Comment: Where/how are you using `createTour`? Is it being used in an express route?

Comment: I think what you're after is similar to the second code block from the bottom of this answer: [Handling errors in express async middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51391081)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`req,res,next` are parameters of the `fn` function. These are variables that are *local* to the function's own execution context. When you *call* a function, you're supposed to provide *values* for these parameter variables. You cannot access those variables themselves, as they don't exist yet before the call is getting executed.