# How should I call an async function from within Express middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I've been able to simplify this problem to a single-file example that should be easily reproducible with Express 5.0.0-beta.1.

I am writing an Express middleware function that implements basic JWT authentication. The logic is very simple: extract the token from the `Authorization` header (returning 401 if not present/malformed) and then plug the token into an internal function that we'll call `validateToken`, which returns a Promise. **Note:** I believe that this is a unique question on Stack Overflow, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51391080/11875370) is about making an async call from *within the endpoint handler*, but I need to make an async call from *within the middleware function*.

I've tried to implement this in the following way:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

class HttpError {
    constructor(status, message) {
        this.status = status
        this.message = message
    }
}

// Auth middleware
const authMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {

        const token = req.header('Authorization');
        if (!token) {
            console.info("No JWT in request")
            return next(new HttpError(401, 'Unauthorized'))
        }
    
        const regex = /^Bearer (.+)$/;
        const jwt = regex.exec(token)[1];
    
        if (!jwt) {
            console.info("Malformed JWT")
            return next(new HttpError(401, 'Unauthorized'))
        }

        return validateToken({jwt: jwt, path: '/secured'})
            .then((response) => next())
            .catch(err => next(new HttpError(403, 'Forbidden')))   
}
app.use(authMiddleware)

// Endpoint definitions
app.get('/secured', (req, res) => {
    console.info('endpoint handler invoked')
    res.send('Valid token')
})

// Error handlers
function errorMiddleware(error, req, res, next) {
    console.info(`error middleware hit: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
    if (!error.status || error.status >= 500) {
        return res.status(error.status || 500).send();
    }
            
    res.status(error.status).json({ message: error.message });
}
app.use(errorMiddleware)

app.listen(8080);
```

When I send a request without the `Authorization` header and one of the first two `if` blocks are triggered (returning `next(new HttpError(...)`), the application immediately issues a 401 Unauthorized response to the client. But when I send a request *with* a token in the header, the application hangs indefinitely on the final `return validateToken(...)` line of the middleware function.

I was told that Express 5.x automatically handles rejected promises in middleware functions, but even after upgrading to Express 5 the application still hangs indefinitely when calling the async function `validateToken`.

Comment: It's a known bug that express ignores errors thrown in promises. You have to handle them yourself. Take a look at: [Handling errors in express async middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391080/handling-errors-in-express-async-middleware)

Comment: I tried using the code snippet in the answer (try/catching the async function call) and I get the exact same behavior: when I send an invalid token, the request hangs indefinitely.

Comment: @DanielKesner If you called `next(error)` inside the `catch` block, then provide an error handler as well. See: [The default error handler](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#the-default-error-handler)

Comment: Main issue in your code is unhandled promise rejection of the middleware. If `validateToken` returns a rejected promise, then that will result in the rejection of the promise returned by the async middleware function but that promise rejection isn't handled in your code.

Comment: @konrad - It's not a known bug.  It's a missing feature in Express v4.  Express was architected long before promises were a thing and the return value from a request handler is not used at all in Express.  For it to see a rejected promise from an `async` handler, Express would have to pay attention to the return value, see if it was a promise and, if so, hook up a reject handler to it.  That's just not something Express v4 has implemented.  This new feature is in Express v5.

Comment: @jfriend00 I bumped to Express 5.x and I still see the same behavior, promises returned by the `validateToken` method just cause the application to hang indefinitely. Based on what you said, I would expect upgrading to Express 5.x to immediately fix this problem. Can you try running the updated code snippet in the main question with Express 5.x and let me know if you see it working successfully?

Comment: Can you show us the code for `validateToken()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `validateToken` function I was calling had some very weird behavior - prior to validating the token, it awaited an HTTP call to the AWS Metadata service to fetch some information about the system. I thought that I was making a mistake with my async Express code, but in reality **the call to AWS was taking 75 seconds to timeout** and after timing out, the handlers functioned exactly as they should have.

Here is a single-file example of an Express server that awaits an async operation *within the middleware*, hopefully this helps someone in the future:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

class HttpError {
    constructor(status, message) {
        this.status = status
        this.message = message
    }
}

// Auth middleware
const authMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {

        const token = req.header('Authorization');
        if (!token) {
            console.info("No JWT in request")
            return next(new HttpError(401, 'Unauthorized'))
        }
    
        const regex = /^Bearer (.+)$/;
        const jwt = regex.exec(token)[1];
    
        if (!jwt) {
            console.info("Malformed JWT")
            return next(new HttpError(401, 'Unauthorized'))
        }

        // Assume that `validateToken` is a function returning a promise with either the token's claims or an error
        return this.validateToken({jwt: jwt, path: '/secured'})
            .then((response) => next())
            .catch(err => next(new HttpError(403, 'Forbidden')))   
}

// Invoke authMiddleware function for all endpoints that begin with '/secured'
app.use('/secured', authMiddleware)

// Endpoint definitions
app.get('/secured', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Valid token')
})

app.get('/unsecured', (req, res) => res.send('Unsecured endpoint'))

// Error handlers
function errorMiddleware(error, req, res, next) {
    console.debug(`Error caught by Express error handler: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
    if (!error.status || error.status >= 500) {
        return res.status(error.status || 500).send();
    }
    
    res.status(error.status).json({ message: error.message });
}
app.use(errorMiddleware)

app.listen(8080);
```